# Elastic search cluster level analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, elasticsearch-2.0

How can I define one custom analyzer that will be used in more than one index (in a cluster level)? All the examples I can find shows how to create a custom analyzer on a specific index.

My analyzer for example:

```
PUT try_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "od_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [
            "dog, cat => animal",
            "john, lucas => boy",
            "emma, kate => girl"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "od_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "od_synonyms"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "record": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer":"standard",
            "search_analyzer": "od_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how to change my analyzer scope to cluster level?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "scope" for analyzers. But you can do something similar with [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html):

```
PUT /_template/some_name_here
{
  "template": "a*",
  "order": 0,
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "od_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [
            "dog, cat => animal",
            "john, lucas => boy",
            "emma, kate => girl"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "od_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "od_synonyms"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And at `"template"` you should put the name of the indices that this template should be applied to **when the index is created**. You could very well specify `"*"` and matching all the indices. I think that's the best you can do for what you want.